# Are questions about LilyPond syntax on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question title says it all.

I can see two ways this can go:
  either it *is* on-topic by virtue of text-based DTP or
  it *is not* on-topic because it is not based on any TeX engine despite its syntactic similarities (to my knowledge).

The type of question I would ask is how to typeset a specific chord (`<b d' g'>`) in [chord notation](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/notation/chord-mode).  This question is uncomfortably similar to [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14), but seems to have more to do with [music theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) than typesetting.

Comment: Duplicate of [Where should I ask programming questions regarding lilypond?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3817)

Comment: Don't know how I missed that one.  Thanks!